# Not-case sensitive 'ismember' use in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two cells with the first column as string.  I am currently using `ismember` to match the first column elements in both the cells.  But ismember is case sensitive.  I cannot use strcmpi because the cells are of unequal size.  Could you suggest another approach?

```
cell1 = { 'AAPL' [2001] ; 'GOOG' [1999] ; 'MSFT' [2010] } ; 

cell2 = { 'AMZN' [2009] ; 'HP' [2011] ; 'CSC' [2005] ; 'Goog' [2010] } ;
```

Not-case sensitive approach:

```
tf = ismember(cell1(:,1), cell2(:,1)) ; % tf should be now [0; 1; 0]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions [`lower`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) and [`upper`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/upper.html) operate on cell arrays of strings, so you can use them to convert the strings to all lower or upper case before calling [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
>> tf = ismember(lower(cell1(:, 1)), lower(cell2(:, 1)))

tf =

     0
     1    % <-- there's the 1 you want!
     0
```